# Running Jest describe.each or it.each tests directly from IntelliJ?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, jestjs

In IntelliJ 2019.3 Commercial Edition, is there a way to run individual `describe.each` and `it.each` tests with the "play/debug" button? To even get IDEA to recognize this `test.spec.js` file as a Jest test, I need the `xdescribe` dummy method. Without it, IDEA runs tests with direct Node (no Jest arguments).

[image: Jest describe.each]

Results when right-clicking on the **file** (not individual `it`/`describe` blocks) and running all tests in the file:

[image: Results]

My Run/Debug configurations are nothing special:

[image: Run/debug config]

My package.json dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-each": "^24.9.0",
    "jest-each-object": "^1.0.0",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.23",
    "@types/jest-each": "^24.3.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "mz": "^2.7.0"
  },
```

JetBrain's YouTrack didn't yield any fruitful results, and many users are Community users (no convenient individual "play/debug" buttons), so this is a challenging problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IDE is statically analyzing the source code looking for known code patterns when detecting tests. `describe.each` and `it.each` patterns support will be added in the next major update, see [WEB-35107](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-35107)